# Angluar prints in one line even when the text does not fit

Tags: html, css, angular

I use

```
<div>
     <p>
        {{text}}
    </p>
</div>
```

Text is just string.
And if text lenght out of div width angular anyway spell it in one line. [image]

But `<p>` element width is correct

[image]

So how I can fix it? I want all text in div with line breaks when needed

Answer (score 1):

Apply the following style to the element

> word-break: break-all;

```
<div>
   <p style="word-break: break-all">
    {{text}}
   </p>
</div>
```

Or else you can write a class add use it since it may needed in other places also.

Answer (score 1):

`word-break: break-all;`

```html
    <div>
       <p style="width: 100px; background: aqua; word-break: break-all; ">
        {{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}}
       </p>
    </div>
```

`line-break: anywhere;`

```html
<div>
           <p style="width: 100px; background: aqua; line-break: anywhere; ">
            {{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}}
           </p>
        </div>
```